# Equality of complex numbers in trigonometric form

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

How are these two equal? My teacher said it is obvious, am I missing something?

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}(\cos{kx}+i\sin{kx})=\cos{(1+2+...+n)x}+i\sin{(1+2+...+n)x}$$

Comment: Consider De-Moivre's theorem.

Comment: DeMoivre's Theorem: $(cos(A)+isin(A))*(cos(B)+isin(B))=cos(A+B)+isin(A+B)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remind that: $$\forall k\in\mathbb{N},\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\cos(kx)+i\sin(kx)=e^{ikx}.$$

Comment: Omg, De-Moivre's theorem... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** It is the repeated use of De Moivre's theorem. Note that when trigonometric ratios are multiplied angles are added.